# Lumen fail conecting to remote database due to wrong hostname, Access denied for user

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, phpunit, lumen

I deployed a Lumen project on AWS EC2 machine, the domain for this machine is api.mydomain.com.

I create a PHPUNIT test to check DB conection (using  $this->seeInDatabase ) but when running the test it fail due to 'Access denied for user'.

On the database I granted access for DB_user@api.mydomain.com but the call goes from  DB_user@ec2-12-215-193-141.compute-1.amazonaws.com and it fails.

If I grant access to DB_user@% it works, but it is too risky to keek this configuration.

I don't know if it is due to Lumen configuration, server configuration or phpunit configuration.

Any Hints?

Comment: Where is your DB is it local or on RDS?

Comment: is a remote database on a server on linode cloud.